We have upgraded rest sharp to latest stable version 112 from 106. Token generation API call is failing in latest version
We have upgraded rest sharp to latest stable version 112 and try to generate token through an API by passing client id and secret It is failing. However, if we try to generate similar token using older version of Rest Sharp API(106), works perfectly fine. What chaneg, I need to do in my code snippet to suit the call.
var request = new RestRequest();// new RestRequest("api/attachments", Method.Post);
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.Timeout = 800000;//new TimeSpan(800000);
// request.ReadWriteTimeout = 800000;
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
request.AddHeader("Charset", "utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
JObject jbody = new JObject();
jbody.Add("client_id", client_id);
jbody.Add("client_secret", client_secret);
jbody.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

request.AddParameter("application/json", jbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Response code is 0.
